# Weakening of the perfect set property

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

The perfect set property says that every uncountable set of reals contains a perfect subset.

Now consider the following statement:

> P: For every $X\subset\mathbb{R}$, either $X$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus X$ contains a (non-empty) perfect set.

Clearly, the perfect set property implies the second one. I've heard that the converse is false, but I couldn't find a model of ZF+P (this would obviously entail a failure of choice). Moreover, is it possible to get a model where P holds without assuming the existence of an inaccessible?

Any references for this? I've looked at Jech, Rubin, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484374900151) , and Googled a bunch, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This was studied by John Truss in his paper that you mention,

> *Truss, John*, [**Models of set theory containing many perfect sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(74)90015-1), Ann. Math. Logic 7, 197-219 (1974). [ZBL0302.02024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.02024).

Specker's theorem tells us that the perfect set property implies $\omega_1$ is a limit cardinal in $L$, but without countable choice, $\omega_1$ *can be singular*. And Truss shows that this is consistent with the perfect set property.

Moreover, he shows, in a fairly simple family of models every set of reals can either be well-ordered or it contains a perfect set (and the reals cannot be well-ordered), which is an intermediate statement between your $\rm P$ and the perfect set property. This is even consistent with Dependent Choice to some fixed level.

So now take a set of reals, if it can be well-ordered, then its complement cannot be, and thus contains a perfect set. If your set cannot be well-ordered, then it contains a perfect set.

Comment: It took me a while to appreciate the results in Truss' paper in full. Certainly the first couple of times I read it, it did not fully register in my head what is shown there.

Comment: Okay, I'll look at Truss' paper in more detail, it was fairly overwhelming at first. But knowing the result is in there helps. Thanks!